# Single Instance Application in C++/CLI using Mutex

Tags: c#, c++-cli, pinvoke, single-instance

I am developing a tray icon based application in C++ CLI. I am using Mutex to ensure single instance of my application running at a time. But each time a new instance starts, the current instance's window should go active. 
I am sending a message to the window using PostMessage(Pinvoke). But after 3 or 4 successive run, my application crashes.

Any ideas why that happen. please help!!

The code I have written in the main() function is,

```
Mutex ^mutex = gcnew Mutex(true, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}");
if (mutex->WaitOne(TimeSpan::Zero, true))
{
    // New Instance. Proceed......................
}
else// An instance is already running. Activate it and return
{
    // send our Win32 message to make the currently running instance
    // jump on top of all the other windows
    try
    {

        HWND hWindow = FindWindow( nullptr, "MyWindow" );
        if(hWindow)
            PostMessage(hWindow, WM_ACTIVATE_APP, nullptr,nullptr);
    }
    catch(Exception^ Ex)
    {
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Thanks & Regards,

Rohini

Comment: Adding some code could help.

Comment: Hi @AntonSavin Savin, I have added the code

Comment: Well, you are lying, telling the app that it got activated but not actually activating it.  Such lies have a knack for blowing up in your face.  You must use SetForegroundWindow() instead.  Do avoid re-inventing the wheel, this is already very well supported in .NET.  Use the WindowsFormsApplicationBase class, IsSingleInstance property and StartupNextInstance event.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant. Excuse my ignorance. I did a small research in the way you pointed and I am stuck at the point where I need to Run() my app using the custom ApplicationContext, for which I don't see a way in WindowsFormsApplicationBase.

Comment: Very unclear why you think you need a custom ApplicationContext.  The default one is good enough for everybody.  Normally only used to override the decision when to quit the UI thread, WFAB already has that feature.  You'll have to ask a question about it and properly document it.

Comment: The app is already developed for our client and we don't have a specific main form which will be displayed always. The first form displayed depends on many factors like whether a user is logged in to the app. The main form(to which I PostMessage) I mention here is just a  form used to handle messages and all. It is in the application context that these decisions like which form will be displayed is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of `PostMessage()`:

```
ShowWindowAsync(hWindow, 1); // SW_SHOWNORMAL
SetForegroundWindow(hWindow);
```

Comment: ..Thanks...Things again get complicated by the fact that it is not the main Winow that I should show. My main Window is  only a small Window designed to receive messages. As I told already this is a tray Icon app and in each tray context menu, I show different forms, and the first form displayed depends on whether a user is logged int to the app and so.

Comment: @RohiniSreekanth but don't you find the correct window with `FindWindow` as you showed in the post? You can also use `FindWindowEx` to search for child windows.

Comment: FindWindow and Postmessage succeeds, but its causing a dealy so that when i look in the task manager i can see as many instances of my application running and at some point the app crashes.